# The behavior of bufname is unclear to me

Tags: buffers, plugin-nerdtree

I use NERDTree and try to apply the [recipe](https://github.com/preservim/nerdtree#how-can-i-prevent-other-buffers-replacing-nerdtree-in-its-window) that ensures no one replaces its buffer.

I do the following:

- Start vim
- Execute `:NERDTreeFocus`
- Open some file
- Execute `:q` for file buffer
- (At this point there is one window with NERDTree only)
- Open some other file

There I have NERDTree and former file buffers swapped.

While trying to track down the issue I found the following. Suppose we have this autocmd:

```
autocmd BufEnter * echomsg "Alternate: " . bufnr('#') . " " . bufname('#') | echomsg "Current: " . bufnr('%') . " " . bufname('%')
```

Then I try:

1. Start vim
2. `:vs`
3. `:e 123`
4. `<C-W> j`
5. `<C-W> l`

After step 3 I see the following in messages:

```
"123" [New]
Alternate: 1
Current: 2 123
```

After step 4:

```
Alternate: -1
Current: 1
```

After step 5:

```
Alternate: 1
Current: 2 123
```

My question is: why do I have `Alternate: -1` after step 4 instead of `Alternate: 2 123`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vim stores an alternate file for each window.

1. when vim starts up a new empty bufnr 1 is initialized
2. split, now bufnr 1 is in both windows
3. edit, since bufnr 1 is in both windows, vim must create a new bufnr 2 for the file 123
4. switching to the initial window, where there was no alternate alternate file (# = -1)
5. switching back to second window, where alternate file was bufnr = 1